Prove that if any metric space X is compact, it's complete using open covers definition
Basically title, knowing that every open cover of a metric space $X$ has a finite subcover, prove $X$ is complete.
Proof: Suppose for contradiction that $X$ isn't complete, then there exists an infinite sequence $x_n:\mathbb{N} \to X$ s.t. $x_n$ is Cauchy and doesn't converge to any $p \in X$. By definition of convergence, this means $\exists\epsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall N>0 \space \exists n>N$ s.t. $d(x_n,p) \geq\epsilon$, so choose $\epsilon_p<\epsilon$ for a point $p$ and let $M_p$ be the $\epsilon_p$-neighborhood of $p$. This means that $x_n$ doesn't remain inside $M_p$ forever. Let $k_p$ then be $\max\{n \space|\space x_n \in M_p, x_{n+1} \notin M_p \}$ or $0$ if $\nexists n$ s.t. $x_n \in M_p$, each $M_p$ then contains at most $k_p$ terms of $x_n$, a finite amount. Now consider the cover $\bigcup_p M_p$, since every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover, there is a finite subcover of $\bigcup_p M_p$, and since every $M_p$ only contains a finite amount of $x_n$ terms, this cover contains only a finite amount of $x_n$ terms. But $x_n$ is an infinite sequence, so this is a contradiction, and thus $X$ is complete.

I think I managed to do it but the proof doesn't use the fact that $x_n$ is cauchy so in theory it works for any infinite sequence, which is wrong. Also going from "$x_n$ doesn't remain inside $M$ forever" to "There are a finite amount of $x_n$ terms in $M$" doesn't feel formal enough to me.
Any feedback is appreciated.

Are you in a metric space? Please add these details to your question.

Yes! Sorry I forgot to include it as I was rewriting this for a long time. Fixed it

You can prove this easily if you know the fact that compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness. Hence any cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence. To show that the whole sequence converges now is very easy.

I know that and it's the exercise I did before this, but since the two definitions are equivalent I wanted to prove this directly without sequential compactness.

Why should your max be finite?

i understand. To be honest this looks a bit confusing to me, i would definetly try the direct approach because that seems less confusing to me. But as you said: if you did not use your cauchy ability your proof will be wrong.

I forgot to add the other condition, very sorry. $k$ is meant to be the last index of the sequence for which the sequence is in $M_p$, i.e. the last time $x_n$ "leaves" $M$.

I think you made a mistake: Why should $k_p$ be finite? For arbitrary sequences this is definetly wrong. Maybe this is the point where you have to use that $x_n$ is cauchy.
But i have another proof:
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ a cauchy sequence. Since $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is cauchy:
$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+\exists N_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb N \forall n \in \mathbb N: N_{\epsilon}\leq n \implies d(x_n, x_{N_{\epsilon}}) < \epsilon$$
Let for any positive $\epsilon: B_{\epsilon}:= \{ z\in X\mid d(z,x_{N_{\epsilon}}) \leq \epsilon\}$, the closed $\epsilon$-Ball around the corresponding $x_{N_{\epsilon}}$, note that this contains all $x_n$ for $x_{N_{\epsilon}}\leq n$, and a possible limit point.
Assume: $\emptyset = B:= \bigcap_{\epsilon \in \mathbb R^+}B_{\epsilon}$
$$\implies X= \bigcup_{\epsilon \in \mathbb R^+} B_{\epsilon}^c, \text{ open cover, hence}:\exists \epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_n\in (0,\infty):X=\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_{\epsilon_i}$$
Implying: $$\emptyset =\bigcap_{i=1}^nB_{\epsilon_i}$$
Which is a contradiction, since any of these balls contain all $x_k$ s.t. $\max_{i=1,\dots, n} N_{\epsilon_i} < k$
$$\implies\exists x \in B:\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+\exists N_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb N: d(x_{N_{\epsilon}},x)\leq \epsilon$$
And since $\forall n\in \mathbb N: N_{\epsilon}\leq n \implies d(x_{N_{\epsilon}},x_n) < \epsilon$ one gets by the triangular inequality:
$$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+\exists N_{\epsilon}\in \mathbb N \forall n \in \mathbb N: N_{\epsilon}\leq n \implies d(x_n, x)\leq d(x_n, x_{N_{\epsilon}})+ d(x_{N_{\epsilon}},x) < 2\epsilon$$
Substituting $\epsilon$ gives the required convergence.

This is brilliant! Thank you for your help, even though this proved way more difficult than I imagined.

Thank you! I just thought about how it should be/where the limit should have to be (in these balls ) and then combined it with compactness (which tends to make things work the way you want usually). But i think thats a good example why metric spaces are so cool: you have sequential compactness which tends to make things easier. @Xyon4
